# Open multiple urls in same new tab javascript then stop the last one

Tags: javascript, popup

I using this script to open multiple url in popup

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  var targets = [                          //Place target URL here

        'https://www.google.com', 
      'https://www.bing.com/',
            'https://www.yahoo.com/'

    ];

    var iTarget;

    function nextTarget(){
       affiliate = window.open( targets[iTarget], 'target','');
        if( ++iTarget >= targets.length ) {
            iTarget = 0;
        }
    }

    function showMiniPop() {
        iTarget = 0;
        nextTarget();
        setInterval( nextTarget, 3000 );   //time interval here 3000 = 3 Sec
    }
</script>
```

This open 3 url in popup and rotate every 3 secondes

I want to keep the LAST opened (yahoo.com in my example). Can you help me please ?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. *"I want to keep the LAST opened"* It's all about the user to not close a tab

Comment: My problem is it's doing LOOP, I want to keep the last opened

Comment: remember to clear your interval!

Comment: @AmosIsaila  Can you help me to clearinterval ?

Comment: check my answer @NuxMr

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```js
var targets = [                  //Place target URL here
      'https://www.yahoo.com/',
      'https://www.google.com', 
      'https://www.bing.com/'
    ];

    var iTarget;
    var finishedIteratingAllElements = false;
    var newTab = false;

    function nextTarget(){
        var getLastItem = targets.slice(-1);
        if (targets.slice(0) === targets[iTarget] && !finishedIteratingAllElements) {
            // here we open the first time => yahoo
            yahooAlreadyOpened = true;
            affiliate = window.open( targets[iTarget], 'target','');
        }
        if (targets.slice(0) !== targets[iTarget] && !newTab) {
            // open next tabs in a new tab if not yahoo and we are not yet in new tab
            affiliate = window.open( targets[iTarget], '_blank','');
            newTab = true;
        } else {
            // we have new tab, so open in same
            affiliate = window.open( targets[iTarget], 'target','');
        }
        if (targets.slice(0) !== targets[iTarget] && finishedIteratingAllElements) {
            // if we iterated all elements, then those who are not yahoo, open in same tab
            affiliate = window.open( targets[iTarget], 'target','');
        }
        if( ++iTarget >= targets.length ) {
            iTarget = 0;
        }
        if (getLastItem === targets[iTarget]) { 
            finishedIteratingAllElements = true;
        }
    }

    function showMiniPop() {
        iTarget = 0;
        nextTarget();
        setInterval( nextTarget, 3000 );   //time interval here 3000 = 3 Sec
    }
    showMiniPop();
```